# Highlight cells whose content cannot be parsed as number

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How can I highlight cells whose content is not parsable as number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en) with a custom formula. For example, select cell A1, go to Format/Conditional formatting, select "custom formula" and enter

```
=ISERROR(VALUE(A1))
```

In the same dialog you can  choose the range to which this formatting should be applied.

Comment: thanks, but that "custom formula" doesnt show up in the conditional formatting dialog.

Comment: This feature is available in New Google Sheets only.

Comment: true, can i somehow convert my sheet to the new format?

Comment: Yes, see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6082736?hl=en

Comment: One conversion method that the article doesn't seem to mention is:  download and then upload again.

Comment: ok, i could convert my spreadsheet and your suggested solution works in a new spreadsheet. however in my converted one it does not work for all cells. a large number of cells get highlighted even though they contain a valid number. i even tried to delete and reenter the number.